# useMemo behaves different for inline component vs. normal component

Tags: reactjs

I have the following React code

```js
const { useState, useMemo, Fragment } = React;

function Rand() {
    return <Fragment>{Math.random()}</Fragment>;
}

const App = () => {
    const [show, setShow] = useState(true);
    
    // The inline component gets memoized. But <Rand /> does not
    const working = useMemo(() => <Fragment>{Math.random()}</Fragment>, []);
    // The rand component is not memoized and gets rerendred
    const notWorking = useMemo(() => <Rand />, []);
  
    return(
        <Fragment>
            <button
                onClick={() => {
                  setShow(!show);
                }}>
                {show?"Hide":"Show"}
            </button>
            <br />
            Working: 
            {show && working}
            <br />
            Not Working: 
            {show && notWorking}
        </Fragment>
    );
}

ReactDOM.render(
    <App />,
    document.getElementById("root")
);
```

```html
<div id="root"></div>

<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/react/17.0.2/umd/react.development.js"></script>
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/react-dom/17.0.2/umd/react-dom.development.js"></script>
```

It uses `useMemo` 2 times.

The first time it uses an inline component to "initialize" and memoize a component ( `const working = useMemo(() => <>{Math.random()}</>, []);`)

The second time it uses a component which was made outside the app component (`const notWorking = useMemo(() => <Rand />, []);`)

Both components used in the `useMemo` function have the exact same code, which is `<>{Math.random()}</>`.

Here comes the unexpected part, when I hide (Click the button) and show the two memoized components again, they behave differently. The first one will always show the same random number which it got when it first got initialzied. While the seconds one will re-initialize each time.

#### First render

[image]

#### Second render (hide)

[image]

#### Third render (show again)

[image]

You can see from the screenshots that the first component's random number stays the same, while the second one does not.

## My Questions:

- How can I prevent in both cases to re-render/re-initialize the component?
- Why does it currently behave as it does?

Interestingly, it *does* get memoized if I use a counter instead of show/hide:

```js
const { useState, useMemo, Fragment } = React;

function Rand() {
    return <Fragment>{Math.random()}</Fragment>;
}

const App = () => {
    const [counter, setCounter] = useState(0);
    
    // The inline component gets memoized. But <Rand /> does not
    const working = useMemo(() => <Fragment>{Math.random()}</Fragment>, []);
    // The rand component is not memoized and gets rerendred
    const notWorking = useMemo(() => <Rand />, []);
  
    return(
        <Fragment>
            <button
                onClick={() => {
                  setCounter(c => c + 1);
                }}>
                Update ({counter})
            </button>
            <br />
            Working: 
            {working}
            <br />
            Not Working: 
            {notWorking}
            <br />
            <code>Rand</code> used directly:
            <Rand />
        </Fragment>
    );
}

ReactDOM.render(
    <App />,
    document.getElementById("root")
);
```

```html
<div id="root"></div>

<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/react/17.0.2/umd/react.development.js"></script>
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/react-dom/17.0.2/umd/react-dom.development.js"></script>
```

Here is a codepen to try it yourself https://codepen.io/brandiatmuhkuh/pen/eYWmyWz

Answer (score 2):

> Why does it currently behave as it does?

`<Rand />` doesn't call your component function. It just calls `React.createElement` to create the React element (not an instance of it). Your component function is used to *render* an element instance, if and when you use it. In your "working" example you're doing:

```
<>{Math.random()}</>
```

...which calls `Math.random` and uses its result as text (not a component) within the fragment.

But your "not working" example just does:

```
<Rand />
```

The element is created, but not *used*, and your function isn't called. The "your function isn't called" part may be surprising — it was to me when I started using React — but it's true:

```js
const { Fragment } = React;

function Rand() {
    console.log("Rand called");
    return <Fragment>{Math.random()}</Fragment>;
}

console.log("before");
const element = <Rand />;
console.log("after");

// Wait a moment before *using* it
setTimeout(() => {
    ReactDOM.render(
        element,
        document.getElementById("root")
    );
}, 1000);
```

```html
<div id="root"></div>

<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/react/17.0.2/umd/react.development.js"></script>
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/react-dom/17.0.2/umd/react-dom.development.js"></script>
```

> How can I prevent in both cases to re-render/re-initialize the component?

If you do what you've done in your example, which is to take the mounted component out of the tree entirely, you're unmounting the component instance; when you put it back, your function **will** get called again, so you'll get a new value. (This is also why the version with the counter *doesn't* exhibit this behavior: the component instance remained mounted.)

If you want to memoize what it shows, one approach is to pass that to it as a prop, and memoize what you pass it:

```js
const { useState, useMemo, Fragment } = React;

function Rand({text}) {
    return <Fragment>{text}</Fragment>;
}

const App = () => {
    const [show, setShow] = useState(true);
    
    const working = useMemo(() => <Fragment>{Math.random()}</Fragment>, []);
    const randText = useMemo(() => String(Math.random()), []);

    return(
        <Fragment>
            <button
                onClick={() => {
                  setShow(!show);
                }}>
                {show?"Hide":"Show"}
            </button>
            <br />
            Working: 
            {show && working}
            <br />
            Also Working Now: 
            {show && <Rand text={randText} />}
        </Fragment>
    );
}

ReactDOM.render(
    <App />,
    document.getElementById("root")
);
```

```html
<div id="root"></div>

<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/react/17.0.2/umd/react.development.js"></script>
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/react-dom/17.0.2/umd/react-dom.development.js"></script>
```

Comment: Hey, T.J. great explanation as always! How do you explain the value getting memoized when `counter` is used based on this? And do you have any source that explains the _functional component doesn't gets called_ part? I want to really dig into behind the scenes :)

Comment: @SinanYaman - That's sort of buried in the middle of the above: it seems memoized in the counter example because it's never unmounted. I don't have a good reference for the other, other than [`createElement`](https://reactjs.org/docs/react-api.html#createelement). It helps to remember that `<Rand />` is just JSX for `React.createElement(Rand, null, null)`. Note that it just *remembers* `Rand` for later, if it needs it.

Comment: Hey T.J. thanks for the detailed explanation. I'm still trying to get my head around it. I assume I did expect `useMemo` to have a differnt behavior. Which is; the first time the component inside useMemo is used it get's initialized. After that it get's reused. I thought mounting is not taking into consideration when `useMemo` is used.

Comment: @T.J.Crowder The example I gave with `<>{Math.random()}</>` should highlight the re-render. The issues I'm trying to solve is, that any component `<Rand />` or other should not be re-rendered/re-created until the useMemo array says so. 

In other words the `{Math.random}`, should be able to be repalced with any JSX and should not re-render/re-create. Kind of like a singleton. Is that even doable in react?

Comment: @JürgenBrandstetter - *"The example I gave with `<>{Math.random()}</>` should highlight the re-render."* I don't know what you mean by that. I understand the problem you're trying to solve. You can memoize what you provide to the component, or use CSS to show/hide it, but if it leaves the tree entirely (your original example), it will get re-rendered when put back, because that's a new component instance.

Comment: That's correct. I want to prevent the generation of a new component instance. I want to be able to "save" a component. Like I would save `a = Math.random()`. I want to save `b = <Rand />`

Comment: @JürgenBrandstetter - I don't think you can, if you remove it from the tree and put it back. As I said, you can hide it with CSS...

Comment: @T.J.Crowder I did eventually use CSS to hide it. Thanks you for the tip!

Comment: I'm still trying to get my head around the real issue here. I assume that `b = <Rand />` is later used by react by calling `b()`. And `b()` returns a new React Element when it's called. 

This is different to `a = Math.random()`. Because `a` is an instance of number and not a function.

Is that right?